# Fixed sidebar also fixes the datepicker dropdown. How to solve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have a very simple page with a fixed sidebar at the left of the page. On the right, in the content area, I have a date picker. But I don't want the sidebar to move up and down while I scroll the main content on the right. So I have fixed the content area with the following CSS:

```
.content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But the problem is, because of the above CSS, when the date picker opens in the content area, it doesn't move during scrolling. Here is a complete example in this fiddle:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyxrrkoa/2/)

The date picker doesn't move with the field while scrolling. How can I solve it? Also is there any way I can open it dynamically above or below the input field depending on the browser screen area? (Like currently it opens on the top-right area even it cannot be seen completely as it it set to `pickerPosition: 'top-right'`. Which is very inconvenient.)

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: the datepicker has a absolute position so you will need to calculate the top position on scroll

Comment: Any suggestion how can I achieve that? @madalinivascu

Comment: you use math, like suming some heights,getting some positions, you know math don't you?

Comment: I'm afraid, I have been stuck with it for a very long time. I'd really appreciate any update in that Fiddle or an example. Thanks. @madalinivascu

Comment: so you don't do math :))), i'm working on a solution ,give me some time

Comment: You should consider making the sidebar fixed, not the content.

Comment: Thanks @TahaPaksu. Any suggestion what the changes I should make fix the sidebar in this case?

Comment: I'll prepare an answer.

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the scroll event and some **math**

```
$('.content').on('scroll',function(){
   var offset = $('#datetimepicker').offset().top;//get the offset of the element 
   $('.datetimepicker').css({'top':offset-$('.datetimepicker').height()-20});//set the offset to the picker modal subtract its height and the input height
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/xyxrrkoa/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm a late learner though, but I'll really look into 'Math' too. But I was wondering what about opening it depending on the browser area available above or below as I've mentioned in the question?

Comment: you do some boolean operations in some ifs (you know **math**) to test if the modal fits between the window and the input

Comment: Oh no!!! Again that 'Math'!!!! Would it be too much if I ask an example? I'm a late learner, but I'm a very curious one. But thanks anyway for your help.  :)

Comment: @Ashonko you need to do something like https://jsfiddle.net/xyxrrkoa/6/

Comment: Wow! you are really fast. What you've done in this brief minute, will need a while for me to learn. But fortunately, I'm very eager.
If, I'm not wrong it's a great example what you've done, I cannot thank more but the problem is with `pickerPosition: 'top-right'`. I wanted to open it top-right or bottom-right at the time of opening. Should I look into the current function to achieve that? @madalinivascu

Comment: Actually, not. I mean, when I click the calendar icon, the date picker open on the top-right side of the input area even when it doesn't have enough space. I was hoping in that case, if there is enough space above the input field in the browser, it'll open on the top-right side, but if there is not enough space, it'll open bottom right side of the input field. @madalinivascu

Comment: you can do something similar to the tob/bottom part(using **math** of course )

Comment: No wonder I guessed it before.  :)  Thank you very much @madalinivascu. I really appreciate your lesson today.  :) :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that closing the datetimepicker during scroll is the better idea. Like when the user click on other content or the scrollbar.

```
   $(".content").scroll(function() {
      if ($(".datetimepicker").css("display") == "block")
          $(".datetimepicker").css("display", "none");
  });
```

Comment: That would be a very good solution indeed. Thanks for your effort.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Make the sidebar fixed and having a static width, then apply a left margin with the sidebar width to the content. And there's no need for floating, because the sidebar element is already on a separate layer from the remaining DOM (fixed position)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn: 1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    forceParse: 0,
    showMeridian: 1,
    pickerPosition: 'top-right',
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 120px;
  width: calc(100vw - 120px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker/2.4.4/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker/2.4.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
      <p>Sidebar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      ||<br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br>
    </p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-md-2">Date</label>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="input-group date form_datetime" id="datetimepicker">
          <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-times-circle"></span></span>
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>
      ||<br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br> ||
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. It's really the best approach to deal with the future events in my content area. I really appreciate your time on this.